# When a teacher add an assignment, all the student names appear. How to do it?

Tags: filemaker

[image: ERD]

I have a task to create a database to track student results in a school. I came out with a set of relationships between the tables according to the 3 forms of normalisation(I hope I got it right. If not, please enlighten me).

One feature that I want to put in the Filemaker app is that when a teacher want to enter some assignment marks, he will just need to create a new submission record and all the student names in the class will appear.

I could not think how this feature can be done in Filemaker. I can only create a new submissions record and key in a student's score, then create another new record to do the same thing for a second student.

Can someone help? I am a teacher, not a Filemaker developer so please correct me if my database tables are done wrongly.

Update:
I will like the output to be like this [image: output]

Spreadsheet is not suitable because it can't be used to search/sort easily.

Comment: This looks like something which you would need to write a script to do, have you a layout in mind? Are you trying to create a list of students taking the class with a dropdown for their mark (with a submission button)?

With regards to the relationships, I would say it doesn't need to be the case that they form a straight line (and I think it makes more sense to connect Teacher Profile to Class (rather than Subject) and Enrollment to Submissions (rather than Student Profile)

Comment: I connect Teacher Profile to Subject because each teacher must teach a subject and subject belongs to a class. A class may have many subjects. Students are enrolled into individual subjects(belonging to a class). That's why I connect Student Profile to Enrollment.

Comment: (sorry my misunderstanding was probably my UK-based terminology, where teachers can teach multiple classes and there can be multiple teachers per subjects.) Forgive my continued ignorance, but are assignments1-3 (assessmentID?) related to Subject - won't this grab all assessments the student is doing, rather than on those related to the class? (are there 3 assignments for each subject?) You'll be able to get this output with a table-view, but it's tricky for me to describe exactly how without understanding this structure...

Comment: Which version do you use? It's possible to do this in v11 or earlier with script triggers, but v12 seems to have a bug here.

Comment: @hayden, the assignment1-3 are related to Subject because each Subject will have many assignments during the course of the school term. I would like to grab all the assignments that a student get related to a subject. In the table image above, the data pertains to a particular subject.There will be more assignments that will need to be added. The structure is something that can be done easily with a spreadsheet. But due to the requirement to keep track of results and also result entry for future assignments, my school want to use a database system.

Comment: @MikhailEdoshin, I have both versions. I can do it in v11 but I need someone to point me in the right direction so that I can investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick sample file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9175169/Matrix.zip). It's an old sample and it uses a different (but similar) model. Basically the idea is that: You have a calculated field (I use a repeating field) to display the data. You also have a *global* repeating field that serves as an editing widget. Each time you go to a record you fill this field's reps with data from related records (using a OnRecordLoad trigger). This doesn't mean the field shows the same data for all records, because its conditional formatting rules are set to hide all data; so it only shows a piece of data when you actually enter one of its repetitions. This is the data that can be edited. And finally there's a trigger that fires each time you exit the field and posts your changes to the related table (adds, updates, or deletes).

The sample isn't quite complete because if there's fewer data columns than repetitions, you'd probably want to somehow lock the remaining repetitions; this part isn't done. Otherwise it works fairly well. In FM 12, however, it tends to freeze the app; I reported this to FMI, they acknowledged it, but I don't think it has been fixed already.